# Programmatically test RDP port in Java

Tags: java, rdp

I need to test if some ip/port is running RDP service.
I can't just open a socket like this

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeOut);
```

Because in my application I need to assume that service isn't running in default port.

E.g. For some reason the network admin changed the default port (3389) for RDP and decided to use port 443 (just an example using another tipically open port).

There is one way to test it? Even I need to import an external .jar to do this.

Another important point is my application is cross plataform, so I can't use command lines like "mstsc.exe" to test this.

Comment: I did this example because in an open port the socket will connect as well

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but don't you need to use `DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();` for UDP or did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: Yes, @fbo3264 Could be a DatagramSocket() in my example. What I tried to explain is any simple connection wasn't enough to guarantee that a RDP service.

Comment: Buy starting a Java RDP client (e.g. http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net/) and trying to connect?

Comment: Or you could go the longer way and dig through the RDP spec (http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/e/95ef66af-9026-4bb0-a41d-a4f81802d92c/[MS-RDPBCGR].pdf) to find out what the handshake mechanism is.

Comment: @steve I'll try the properjavardp. I hope it works!